# How do I flatten a table with duplicate names into one with unique names and columns/headers, In SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

From this file with duplicate names[image]

to a single file with unique names but with certain fields transposed across multiple columns.
[image]

Comment: Use the crosstab wizard. Name = row header, type = column header, amount = value (using SUM).

Comment: Crosstab is a feature I'd never used in Access. It was so simple - thank you!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need conditional aggrgation :

```
select name, 
       sum(iif(transactiotype = 'Purchase', OrderAmt, 0)) as Purchase,
       sum(iif(transactiotype = 'Purchase fees', OrderAmt, 0)) as Purchasefees
from table t
group by name;
```

Comment: It works too!! A very handy and flexible alternative. Thank you :)